# How does one tell a button to make sender something else?

Tags: ios, objective-c

A quote from Apple docs: "The sender parameter usually identifies the control sending the action message (although it can be another object substituted by the actual sender)."

How is this accomplished? The "it can be another object" part.

In my case I have a number of buttons that all target the same method which produces a popover with a graphic of a tape measure with a pointer to the number. I have a lot of labels I want to use this on and will put a small button with an icon next to each of them so the user can see the fractional equivalent. I need a way to tell the method the number, which is held by a different label in each case. Making "sender" the label would make this a simple thing.

Comment: You might want to revise this question it's hard to tell what your even talking about...

Comment: If you know about buttons and sender it shouldn't be hard to tell what I am asking for. Are you a mod?

Comment: no i'm not a mod and i didn't down vote you i'm trying to help but I don't even know what your trying to say which is what they probably think too.

Comment: Thanks Shawna. Is it any better?

Comment: Okay, I could just use bunch of if then statements in my method, I was hoping to avoid it, but it's about the same number of lines I suppose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass any sender you want if you invoke the method from somewhere else in your code, but if your action method is being invoked from an action on the control, then the sender will be the control (i.e. UIButton) that invoked the method.  You will need to associate the sensor with the meaning in your code.  The `tag` property may be of use.

The quote you added from Apple is merely indicating that the actual sender *can* supply a different object if it wants to - but it doesn't mean that all objects have the ability to specify a different sender.  In the case of a `UIButton` there is no way of specifying a different sender.